# How can I label the plots inside a Graphic grid?

Tags: plotting

I have some plots as images. I import them in a notebook and arrange them using `GraphicGrid` as follows
[image]

Now I want to label each one in the empty space of the plots, How can do that?

Comment: You can label the plots before putting them into the grid (e.g. using `Epilog`). Alternatively, you could use [`ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid) with its `PlotLabels` option.

Comment: Thanks but none of your  suggestions is not what I asked

Comment: Could you explain why they can't solve your problem? I reread your question, and I'm still not sure what else you could be trying to achieve

Comment: I have no access to produce images. I just already have some images.

Comment: Ah, I see... Then why use `GraphicsGrid` instead of `Grid`? (I'm not sure about all the differences, but as far as I remember, `GraphicsGrid` mostly makes sense with actual `Graphics` objects). That being said: you should be able to add the labels to the individual images using `Labeled` prior to combining them into a grid

Comment: Thanks, I try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** Arbitrary positioning of labels

Using `Inset` they can be positioned anywhere by adjusting the values of `position`.

```
position = {0.75, 0.9}

labeled = 
 MapThread[
  Show[{#1}, 
    Epilog -> 
     Inset[Graphics[{Text[Style[#2, Blue, Bold, 25]]}], 
      Scaled[position]]] &, {images, labels}]

labeled // Partition[#, UpTo@3] & // Grid[#, Alignment -> Top, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

---

Using `Labeled`.

```
images = Table[RandomImage[RandomInteger[{1, 5}], {100, 100}], 9]
labels = "Plot " <> ToString[#] & /@ Range@Length@images
labeled = MapThread[Labeled[#1, #2, Top] &, {images, labels}]

labeled // Partition[#, UpTo@3] & // Grid[#, Alignment -> Top, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks good idea, however I can't place the labels in empty space of my plots, the previous answer seems more flexible in this sense.

Comment: @Wisdom Check the update.

Comment: Great! Now your answer is better!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite there yet, but this may give you (and others) an approach to the problem.

```
plotImages = (paste image here)
```

[image]

```
plotLabels = GraphicsGrid[{
    {"Plot 1", "Plot 2", "Plot 3"},
    {"Plot 4", "Plot 5", "Plot 6"},
    {"Plot 7", "Plot 8", "Plot 9"}
    },
   Spacings -> {30, 20},
   Alignment -> {Right, Top}
   ];
ImageCompose[plotImages, plotLabels, {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

Another imperfect solution but again, it may lead to better ones:

```
labelFunc[text_] := 
      Graphics[{White, Opacity[0.5], Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1.5, 1}], 
        Text[Style[text, Black, Bold], {1.2, 0.75}, Automatic]}];

plotLabels2 = GraphicsGrid[{
    {labelFunc["Plot 1"], labelFunc["Plot 2"], labelFunc["Plot 3"]},
    {labelFunc["Plot 4"], labelFunc["Plot 5"], labelFunc["Plot 6"]},
    {labelFunc["Plot 7"], labelFunc["Plot 8"], labelFunc["Plot 9"]}
    },
   Spacings -> {30, 20},
   Alignment -> {Right, Top}
   ];
ImageCompose[plotImages, plotLabels2, {Center, Center}]
```

[image]

Comment: interesting idea! thanks. However is there a way to arrange labels as they are placed in appropriate locations? for example can I adjust their spaces differently?

Comment: Certainly.  You just need to play around with it a bit.  Maybe setup a `Manipulate` so you can vary the `Spacings` values in realtime until you hit on something.